# JavaFx to Javascript. What is the proper way of passing parameters.

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I am trying to learn how to use JavaFX and I don't know what is the proper way of passing a value to JS and returning a value from JS.

This code works fine, but I don't know if it is proper coding. If you have any suggestion on how to do it properly please tell me.

Thank you.

*JavaFX Class*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NewFXMain extends Application {
    private String msg;
    private String name = "Vader";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("HelloWorld.html").toString());

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("DO you want to know my secret Identity?!!!");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {        
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

               //Pass this to javascript
               webEngine.executeScript("myName("+"'"+ name +"'"+ ")");

               //get return value from javascript
               msg = (String)webEngine.executeScript("hello()");

               printMsg(msg);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();     
        root.getChildren().add(btn);          
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void printMsg(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var me    
            function hello(){
                return me;
            }
            function myName(name){
                me = name;
            }         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use JSON-as-an-Object-Literal (it's "close enough" that it'll work as expected). This will take care of all escaping/injection issues and provide a clean strongerly-typed message-oriented interface.

Comment: `decodeJson(webEngine.executeScript("myName(" + encodeJson(..) + ")")`. The JSON serialization technique is left unspecified.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Also am I doing it right? Is it proper coding?